# Parsing multiple files from a folder and fetching the content as variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function, html-parsing

I am sure a silly question for you but a big one for me as I have just started learning programming.

My issue is like this:

I have multiple HTML files in a folder. Each file has 3 values in 3 lines *(only 1 item in each line)*.

```
Line 1 : Title
Line 2 : Image Link
Line 3 : Details
```

I want to import these files to a **jQuery based Ajax Tabs Script**, I have and the XHTML part of it is like this:

```
<ul class="mytabs" id="tabs">
    <li class="current"><a href="./tabs/tab-1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="./tabs/tab-2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="./tabs/tab-3.html">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="./tabs/tab-1.html">Tab 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="./tabs/tab-2.html">Tab 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="./tabs/tab-3.html">Tab 6</a></li>

</ul>
<div class="mytabs-container" id="tabs-container">
    Loading. Please Wait...
</div>
```

What I want is to parse these HTML files and the Title in Tab's Name position, Image Link and Details in the Tab Container and The link to that file in the `href` before tabs title so that the final product looks something lkike this:

```
<ul class="mytabs" id="tabs">
    <li><a href=<?php echo $linkToFile?>><?php echo $title ?></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="mytabs-container" id="tabs-container">
    Loading. Please Wait...
    <?php echo $imageLink?>
    <?php echo $details?>
</div>
```

I need a PHP or jQuery script which should do the following:

1. ***Loop*** and get the contents of all the HTML files from the folder
2. Fetch content in the form of a ***variable*** so that I can placed them as shown above.
3. Fetch the ***link to file*** too as a variable so that it can also be placed as the link to tabs.

Is this possible? If yes how can I achieve that.

Kindly help.

Comment: i know is kinda out of the question, but i totally recommend the use of XML files here. you can then parse them using the SimpleXML class in PHP.

believe me, in the future is better to use XML files to store this kind of info

:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, then, if you want to read a file in php, you can use something like:

```
$myfile = 'info.htm';
$lines = file($myfile);   
$info = array('title'=>$lines[0], 'image'=>$lines[1], 'details'=>$lines[2]);
echo '<h1>'.$info['title'].'</h1>
      <img src="'.$info['image'].'" alt="'.$info['title'].'"/>
      <p>'.$info['details'].'</p>';
```

obviously, you have to run that for every .htm file

Comment: Wow now that is some stuff. But how does it loop through all files in the folder. If I am not wrong I believe this will parse just one file. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: yes, this will just parse one file. for reading lots of files i'll have to see how files are organized (in one folder, differents folders, etc). anyways the function for reading a directory in PHP is: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php i suggest you to use the "Example #1 List all files in a directory" code

Comment: Yes @Yzmir. You are correct glob() is fetching all the files. Thanks for the suggestion.